# Passing img src via form into DB with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a form with lets say 3 images. I need to pass selected img SRC into Mysql DB via PHP.

If the user checks 1st image, the image src should be inserted into user_pic table to url_picture field.

```
    <form action="" method="POST">;
        <input type="image" src="/some/src1">;
        <input type="image" src="/some/src2">;
        <input type="image" src="/some/src3">;
        <input type="submit" name="send" id="send" value="send">
    </form>
```

How can i pass SRC of selected IMG and insert it with php?

Comment: there's no javascript/php/mysql here, only html and your question is unclear, and if you've no code that you tried, it also makes it too broad.

Comment: and an image input is probably not what you want here.

Comment: I'm on the fence here as to how I should vote to close this question; as unclear or too broad. So; have you any (more) code to share with us? Can you respond to my comments or are you just responding to answers? I'm trying to help you out here, btw, but you haven't given us much to work with.

Comment: Sorry, i just updated my question.

Comment: Instead of `src` use `value`. You must also `name` your inputs. Once you do this all of the values will become available in PHP's `$_POST` array.

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i managed to achive what i needed with the help of @Jay_Blanchard 
Just had to add name and value to my input

```
<input type="radio" name="img" value="img/src/" src="img/src/">
```

and retrive it via _POST

```
$img_src= $_POST['img'];
```

eveything is working fine now

Comment: Thanks for giving me credit. Glad to help. Just remember that every form name must be unique unless you're creating an array.